# How to implement SocketIO in Django ASGI

Tags: django, socket.io, daphne, python-socketio, asgi

I tried this; https://github.com/ly3too/django-channels-with-socket.io But I keep getting 404 for the socket-io. Are there any other methods to implement the socket io?

Comment: If you have a specific problem with this example application you are using or you think it has bugs, then maybe you should ask the author on GitHub. Else, please add more details to your question. You are getting 404 on what exact URL? What code are you using to initialize the Socket.IO server? These things are necessary to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.